# Limit on Batch class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, governorlimits, schedulebatch

If I run a batch class every night, that goes over 10000 leads every night and updates a field. Would I get the limit exceeded error considering the huge number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limits apply to a transaction**

- A batchable `execute()` is a transaction. There are 0..n execute transactions per batch depending on the number of sobjects returned in the `start()` method and the size of the scope parameter when the batchable is invoked (default is 200, min is 1, max is 2000). So, if you had 10,000,000 leads and scope was default 200, you would have 50,000 `execute()` transactions.
- A batchable finish() is a transaction - there is only one per batch

If all your execute() does is update a Lead in the execute()'s scope argument with new fields, then you will not run into DML row limits

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you structure your batch. If you put the DML Operations in your `execute` method, then you are using the interface and chunking appropriately, so you would only process 200 records at a time (or some other number if you change the batch size). The maximum batch size is 2000 records, so you would still not be able to increase it to the point you would get `LimitException` (barring excessive consumption in your triggers).

If you put all of the DML Operations in your `finish` method, then you would be using the batch incorrectly, and likely would exceed governor limits.